# How to access the below json value

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to access the value `DepartmentId` but getting error as value doesn't exists.

I can get the values inside the curly braces when I try to access the `DepartmentId`, I'm getting error.

Below is my map function

```
 r.PrimarySearchResults.map((value) => {
console.log(value)}
)
```

I can get `value.Rank` but not `value.DepartmentId`

Below is the JSON object I got. This is when I expand the Object.

```
{Rank: "16.9111518859863", DocId: 
"17598046715456", Title: "HubSite", SPSiteUrl: "https://amoghtelkar.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite2", 
WebTemplate: "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING", …}
Culture: "en-US"
DepartmentId: "{3d408bfe-9172-4df5-b36e-863c066e9ada}"
DocId: "17598046715456"
PartitionId: "51ddbb65-42e8-4906-82e4-8d97c6626ef7"
Rank: "16.9111518859863"
RenderTemplateId: "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default.js"
ResultTypeId: "0"
SPSiteUrl: "https://amoghtelkar.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite2"
SiteId: "3d408bfe-9172-4df5-b36e-863c066e9ada"
Title: "HubSite"
UniqueId: "{F08C7BCE-C886-4A09-AA22-D66879DD5252}"
UrlZone: "0"
WebId: "edec632a-5671-49bd-a7fe-27a6e851f09a"
WebTemplate: "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING"
__proto__: Object
```

**Find the below image**
[image: Please find the image]

Comment: can you tell me error that you are getting

Comment: Property 'DepartmentId' does not exist on type 'SearchResult'

Comment: as i can check in my system i am getting value like this '{3d408bfe-9172-4df5-b36e-863c066e9ada}'

Comment: `DepartmentId` is inside the object in the above object, so no need to do a map() here, why dont you try `r.PrimarySearchResults.DepartmentId`. Please try and let me know the result

Comment: your departmendId is a string, so even though it has curly braces, it does not make any difference, it is still a string. so if you can console.log(value.rank); and get "16.9111518859863", you should be able to console.log(value.departmentId) and get "{3d408bfe-9172-4df5-b36e-863c066e9ada}"

Comment: @AkhilAravind I have a feeling that the printed object is just one of the results. if that is true, then using map is correct

Comment: @GlenK thats correct, if so `value.DepartmentId` should give result. If not we need the full json object to debug.

Comment: @AkhilAravind  I have added the image.

Comment: @user8535404 from the above posted image, its clear that `value.DepartmentId` should give you the result, some how if its not working, did you tries `value['DepartmentId']`. try this also. If you get error, post a fiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

Tried arranging your JSON object, seems that DepartmentId is not included in the JSON

```
{
    Rank: "16.9111518859863", 
    DocId: "17598046715456", 
    Title: "HubSite", 
    SPSiteUrl: "https://amoghtelkar.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite2", 
    WebTemplate: "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING", }

Culture: "en-US" DepartmentId: "{3d408bfe-9172-4df5-b36e-863c066e9ada}" DocId: "17598046715456" PartitionId: "51ddbb65-42e8-4906-82e4-8d97c6626ef7" Rank: "16.9111518859863" RenderTemplateId: "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default.js" ResultTypeId: "0" SPSiteUrl: "https://amoghtelkar.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite2" SiteId: "3d408bfe-9172-4df5-b36e-863c066e9ada" Title: "HubSite" UniqueId: "{F08C7BCE-C886-4A09-AA22-D66879DD5252}" UrlZone: "0" WebId: "edec632a-5671-49bd-a7fe-27a6e851f09a" WebTemplate: "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING"
```

Try this:

var value = JSON.parse(value);
console.log(value.DepartmentId);

Comment: Is that a string?

Comment: this is a wrong solution, I dont know how it gets upvoted, check the attached image

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the full JSON object being returned should be able to be parsed into an object and then gotten.

If your response object is `PrimarySearchResults`, you should be able to do:

```
r.PrimarySearchResults.DepartmentId;
// should return {3d408bfe-9172-4df5-b36e-863c066e9ada}
```